# Update Comment in Laravel

Tags: laravel, insert-update, laravel-6

I am new at Laravel and I want to use if statement inside Laravel Controller.
So I have a form tag where I can add comments. I want to edit comments in the same form.
Here is my form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="/hotels/{{$id}}" name="review_hotel">
     @csrf
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" style="height:100px"
                   placeholder="Write your review"></textarea>
         @error('comment')
             <p class="text-danger">{{$message}}</p>
         @enderror
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn_1" id="submit-review">
</form>
```

I have a script, with the help of this script I can add a comment that I want to change to the textarea.
After this I have no idea how to update it in my controller.
This is CommentController:

```
public function comment(CommentRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->object_id = $id;
        $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
        $comment->comment = $request['comment'];
        $comment->save();
        return redirect('/hotels/'.$id);
    }
```

I think I need to write "if" statement in my controller, but I don't know how.
maybe there is a simpler way to update comment?

Answer (score 0):

On your model Comment.php mark form variables as fillable

```
public $fillable = ['object_id', 'user_id', 'comment'];
```

then use this Model function (Eloquent)

```
Comment::updateOrCreate(
[
'object_id' => ...,
'user_id' => ...,
],
[
'object_id' => ...,
'user_id' => ...,
'comment' => ...,
]
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Comment: This does not allow for multiple comments by the same person on the same object. Should probably be sending the ID to the controller.

Comment: @Hášíl Páůďýál how can i catch the comment id to let know so what comment i want to change?

Comment: @FuadFarhadoghlu the first param you pass on updateOrCreate() is you where clause of query and the second paramater is the update value. By this method as mentioned by Thomas there will be only one comment by on user on database

Comment: @Thomas Exactly! have you got any idea for my task?

Comment: you want multiple comments by single user? and also update previous one?

Comment: @HášílPáůďýál but i have multiple comments on same object as Thomas said

Comment: just to confirm... you have multiple comments on same object by same user? or multiple comments on same object not by same user?

Comment: @HášílPáůďýál multiple comments on same object by same user. ))

Comment: If you are editing one comment at a time, along with textarea on your edit form pass the comment_id also,

<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{$comment->id}}">